# Error when chaining expect in protractor

Tags: angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm using protractor for e2e testing on an Angular application.

With this test:

```
it('Environnement et logo sont affichés', () => {
  browser.refresh();

  expect(dashboard.getTextByCss('.tag-css')).toEqual('value');
  expect(dashboard.getElementByCss('img[src*=\'image-name.png\']').isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```

I have this pending status:

[image: Pending status screenshot]

If I comment one of **expect** instruction, no pending status, the test succeed.
Please what can be the problem?

Comment: How are the `getTextByCss` and `getElementByCss` implemented?

Comment: @alecxe: They are both methods, with single instruction        
  `getTextByCss:  return element(by.css(css)).getText();`                             
  `getElementByCss: return element(by.css(css));`